# bind shell program to user as root

Tags: linux, scripting, sudo

I have an embedded system I have been developing. I would like to bind a program called HHPConfig, which I wrote and needs root permissions for setting network interfaces, rebooting etc..., to a user, admin, which can log in through telnet and rs232.

I edited the line in /etc/passwd to be:

```
admin:x:1001:1001:Admin User,,,:/home/admin:/usr/bin/HHPConfig
```

I also added the user to the group sudo.

I don't know what to do past there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered [making the executable's owner root and setuid'ing it](http://www.tuxation.com/setuid-on-shell-scripts.html)?